# python / django using a variable as a dict key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.6 and Django 2.0. I have a dict/json like this:

```
dict = [
    {'object A': '100'},
    {'object B': '101'},
    {'object C': '102'},
]
```

and:

```
data = [
    {'title': 'object A', 'description': 'Some Text'},
    {'title': 'object B', 'description': 'Some Text'},
    {'title': 'object C', 'description': 'Some Text'},
]
```

then try and access that number in another function

```
output = []
for x in range(0, len(dict)):
    j = {
        'id': x,
        'title': data[x]['title'],
        'description': data[x]['description'],
        'value': dict[x][data[x]['title']],
    }
    output.append(j)
```

The issue I'm running into is that data[x]['title'] within dict[x][] is coming out as a string and not a slice.

I've tried splitting the title before putting it in, i've tried manually adding ' before and after.

My first question is, is that possible to do? if so, how would I achieve that?

My second question is, is there a better way to achieve that, perhaps with .keys() or something along those lines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Calling a list of dicts `dict`? That's two bad practices in a single line.

Comment: What does "a string not a slice" mean?

Comment: The output looks fine with the data and code you've given.

Answer (score 0):

If your data and dict list can be guaranteed to have the one-to-one mapping relationship, and all the items in each list are distinct by keys, then the codes could be optimized like the followings, using the sort by related keys trick:

```
def gen_output(my_dict_list, my_data_list):
    my_dict_list.sort(key=lambda x: next(iter(x.keys()), None))
    my_data_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['title'])

    output = [{
        'id': idx,
        'title': my_data_list['title'],
        'description': my_data_list['description'],
        'value': my_dict[my_data_list['title']],
    } for idx, (my_dict, my_data_list) in enumerate(zip(my_dict_list, my_data_list))]

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_dict_list = [
        {'object A': '100'},
        {'object B': '101'},
        {'object C': '102'},
    ]

    my_data_list = [
        {'title': 'object B', 'description': 'Some Text'},
        {'title': 'object A', 'description': 'Some Text'},
        {'title': 'object C', 'description': 'Some Text'},
    ]
    print(gen_output(my_dict_list, my_data_list)
```

and then you can get the result likes this:

```
[{'description': 'Some Text', 'id': 0, 'title': 'object A', 'value': '100'},
 {'description': 'Some Text', 'id': 1, 'title': 'object B', 'value': '101'},
 {'description': 'Some Text', 'id': 2, 'title': 'object C', 'value': '102'}]
```